# mysql.connector is returning an error when trying to connect to database on localhost

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-connector-python

The following is the python script I am trying to run to connect to a database and it is throwing an error.

#### Code:

```
import mysql.connector as mariadb

DB_USER = 'username'
DB_PASS = 'password'
DB_NAME = 'databaseName'

#DATABASE Connection
DB = mariadb.connect(host='localhost',port=3306,database=DB_NAME,user=DB_USER,password=DB_PASS)

cursor = DB.cursor()
```

#### Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 583, in connect
    **kwargs)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/socket.py", line 724, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "importIntoDB.py", line 27, in <module>
    on = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',user='DB_USER',password='DB_PASS',db='DB_NAME',charset='utf8mb4',cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 94, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 325, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 630, in connect
    raise exc
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")
```

My process so far:

**1.** I verified that the login details are correct by logging in manually

**2.** I tried a second library for mysql connections (PyMySQL) and it throws the same error

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try indicate the ip (`127.0.0.1`) instead of `"localhost"`